# how to display the array inside an array of objects using ngFor Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I need to display the array quality which is located inside an array of objects. I have tried calling it in `ngFor` using the code below. Is there something wrong with my usage of `ngFor`?

```ts
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Name</th>
                       <th>Quality1</th>
                       <th>Quality2</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor"let item of people">
                         <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                         <td *ngFor"let item of people.quality">item.quality1</td>
                         <td *ngFor"let item of people.quality">item.quality2/td>
                       </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
   })

  export class AppComponent{    
     people: any = [{Name:"John", quality:[{quality1: "nice", quality2: "humble"}]}, {Name:"Dave", quality:[{quality1: "kind", quality2: "caring"}]} ];
  }
```

As of now only the names are appearing in the table but I would also like the quality to appear.

Comment: What are the second and third loops supposed to be doing? Will every person have two qualities? Why are the qualities in a map? Why use `i` as the name of each person in the loop? You're missing a closing backtick too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the second and third loop are going to display the the quality of a person, I use "let item of people" and "let item of people quality" in my real code this is just a shortcut

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there a way to display my array using ngFor?

Comment: The second loop should be over `i.quality`, but your data model seems very weird and you're going to end up with an odd-looking table. Please show a [mcve] of real code, rewriting it badly is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We can simply iterate the loop inside by modifying the second loop

```
        <tr *ngFor="let item of people">
            <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let quality of item.quality">{{ quality }}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let quality2 of item.quality2">{{quality2}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-container>` to combine several nodes with `*ngFor` without introducing another element to the DOM:

```
<ng-container *ngFor"let item of people.quality">
  <td>item.quality1</td>
  <td>item.quality2/td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you could also bind like that:

```
                   <tr *ngFor="let item of people">
                     <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                     <td *ngFor="let item of people.quality">{{item.quality.[quality1]}}</td>
                     <td *ngFor="let item of people.quality">{{item..quality.[quality2]}}</td>
                   </tr>
```